# Alternative to Cucumber?

Tags: cucumber, bdd

When doing BDD, it seems that Cucumber is the default tool to specify behaviors, however the Cucumber website and articles look a bit out of date and not very active.

What are the alternatives ?

Answer (score 4):

- [Cucumber](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) is active, functionally, stable and very easy and productive to use.
- [Serenity BDD](http://www.thucydides.info/#/) is a bundle of Cucumber with WebDriver, but it is clunky and badly over-engineered.
- [JBehave](http://jbehave.org/) is an alternative, it is more complex and a much steeper learning curve than Cucumber.

Answer (score 4):

A very nice library with advanced tooling for Eclipse: Jnario

- http://jnario.org

Comment: The tools of this library look really nice. Unfortunately, it seems to be very Java centric ?!

Comment: Yes, but you can use it with any language, that has decent Java binding like Ruby (jruby), Python (Jython), ...

Comment: I was more looking for something that supports Objective-C, Java, C++, Javascript and C# ;)

Comment: This is a quite wide range. In frameworks like cucumber you have to specify/implement steps in a selected programming language. I can't imagine, how you want to get all those languages supported simultaneously.

Comment: Not necessarily support simultaneously - however if you have a unity3d project for Android and iOS (including native code) you need to have support for all of the languages except JS. As soon as you add HTML5 views or a website that somehow interacts with the apps to the project you also have JavaScript.

Comment: Ok, I agree. This is very complex not only from testing view point.

Comment: Yes, it is complex, but "normal" for a cross-platform mobile unity app/game. ;)

Answer (score 4):

One that I have found in the past year since I posted the question:

- [Robot Framework](http://robotframework.org)

Answer (score 0):

For Java developers I really like JGiven. It is a bit more 'low level' than Cucumber (In theory Gherkin files could be written by business people..) as the tests are written in Java code. But I never found this to be a problem as I found usually the devs end up writing the Gherkin anyway.
Very easy to use and it also generates nice html reports. the website has good docs and youtube conference videos.